# filter path and filename within text

Tags: php, regex, split

i'm desperately trying to figure out how to get all paths and filenames from a specific string.

ex.g.

```
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.1') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.1') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.1') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.1#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
```

should result in an array containing:

```
../fonts/, fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.1
../fonts/, fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.1
../fonts/, fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.1
../fonts/, fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.1#fontawesomeregular
```

What i got until now is following regex:

```
url\(\'(.*?)\/(.*?)\'
```

The problem with this is that i get following:

```
.., /fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.1
.., /fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.1
.., /fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.1
.., /fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.1#fontawesomeregular
```

So, what do I have to consider in order to get the last occurence of / within the path?

Thx for your help,
p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular case this regex should do the work.

```
((?<=url\(\')(?:[^'\/]+\/)+)([^\/']+(?=\'))
```

see the **DEMO** [here](http://regex101.com/r/jA2zE2)

Comment: what would be the solution to having these apostrophes (') optional? such as: url(path/to/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.1)? i tried ((?<=url\()(?:\')?, but it's not really what i want ...

Comment: Try this `(?:url\(\'?)((?:[^'\/]+\/)+)([^'()]+)`

Comment: fantastic :) thank you! it's a shame that i can't figure that out on my own actually.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$s = "src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.1') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.1') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.1') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.1#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');";

if (preg_match_all("~url *\('(\.\./fonts/)(.*?)'\)~i", $s, $arr)) {
   print_r($arr[1]);
   print_r($arr[2]);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ../fonts/
    [1] => ../fonts/
    [2] => ../fonts/
    [3] => ../fonts/
)
Array
(
    [0] => fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.1
    [1] => fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.1
    [2] => fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.1
    [3] => fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.1#fontawesomeregular
)
```

Comment: the path is not restricted to start with "..\fonts". i pointed out the issue with "\". thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested here https://www.debuggex.com/ and it worked:

```
([.][.].?)\/(.*?)\'
```

Comment: as a matter of fact, the path does not always start with "..". The intention was to find the last "\" within the path no matter how it started. but thank you anyway.